# why inline element take width more in html

Tags: jquery, html, css

could you please tell me why inline element take more width

here is my code
https://jsbin.com/jawoyutuhi/1/edit?html,output
[image]

why it taking this space .

```
<html>
<style>
    .red {
        color: red;
    }
    .mb-0 {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .inlineBlock {
        display:inline-block
    }
    .customInput {
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .customInputContainer {
        font-size: 10px;
        padding-top: 4px;
    }
    .customGridCell {
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
    }
</style>
<head> </head>
<body>
<div style="width: 700px;height: 842px;padding: 15px">



    <div>
        <div class="customInputContainer inlineBlock">
            <div class="inlineBlock red">
                <label>
                    <b>
                        Mobile Number Alloted
                        <sup>*</sup>
                    </b>

                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="inlineBlock" style="    width: 45%;
                    margin-left: 4px; padding: 0px;
                    vertical-align: sub;">
                <table style="border-spacing: 1px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="customGridCell"></td>
                        <td class="customGridCell"></td>
                        <td class="customGridCell"></td>
                        <td class="customGridCell"></td>
                        <td class="customGridCell"></td>
                        <td class="customGridCell"></td>
                        <td class="customGridCell"></td>
                        <td class="customGridCell"></td>
                        <td class="customGridCell"></td>
                        <td class="customGridCell"></td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: form where this width come

Comment: Because you have `width:45%` inlined into the HTML?

Comment: what is solution

Comment: solution for what? what is your goal?

Comment: to remove this extra space

Comment: See answer, it should fit your need

Answer (score 1):

You have a width of 45% in **.inlineBlock** so that's why the width is not what you are expecting.

You could just remove it and change the width of individual **.customGridCell** to whatever you want like so :

```
<html>
<style>
    .red {
        color: red;
    }
    .mb-0 {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .inlineBlock {
        display:inline-block
    }
    .customInput {
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .customInputContainer {
        font-size: 10px;
        padding-top: 4px;
    }
    .customGridCell {
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 25px;
        width: 15px;
    }
</style>
<head> </head>
<body>
<div style="width: 700px;height: 842px;padding: 15px">



    <div>
        <div class="customInputContainer inlineBlock">
            <div class="inlineBlock red">
                <label>
                    <b>
                        Mobile Number Alloted
                        <sup>*</sup>
                    </b>

                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="inlineBlock" style=" 
                    margin-left: 4px; padding: 0px;
                    vertical-align: sub;">
                <table style="border-spacing: 1px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="customGridCell"></td>
                        <td class="customGridCell"></td>
                        <td class="customGridCell"></td>
                        <td class="customGridCell"></td>
                        <td class="customGridCell"></td>
                        <td class="customGridCell"></td>
                        <td class="customGridCell"></td>
                        <td class="customGridCell"></td>
                        <td class="customGridCell"></td>
                        <td class="customGridCell"></td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I just removed the width specified in **.inlineBlock** and reduced the width of **.customGridcell**, you could just put whatever you want it to be.

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t128rkyn/).